# Error instaling @reach/router with react v17

Tags: reactjs, npm, reach-router

I'm working with React and I tried to use `@reach/router`, but when I try to install for the console, I had this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: curso-platzi-react-avanzado@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@reach/router
npm ERR!   @reach/router@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\JESUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JESUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-14T17_28_52_648Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Reach Router needs React (and React DOM) version 15 or 16. See [in package.json](https://github.com/reach/router/blob/d2c9ad06715c9d48c2d16f55f7cd889b626d2521/package.json#L30). So, you need to downgrade your React Version.

Answer (score 1):

For React 17 or React 18, you'll have to do `npm i @gatsbyjs/reach-router` instead. More details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gatsbyjs/reach-router

Comment: FYI this package is described to be used for React 18 only, YMMV.